# Spring Boot Maven Plugin With Maven Shade Plugin - Replace single class in dependency

Tags: java, spring, maven, maven-shade-plugin

I have project with Spring Boot. It uses Spring Boot Maven Plugin.
I need to replace single class in one of my dependencies with my own implementation. I am struggling with it. I am running into cuch problems as no main class found, failed to get nested archive or invalid signature file digest.

Here is my shade plugin config:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <configuration>
        <keepDependenciesWithProvidedScope>true</keepDependenciesWithProvidedScope>
        <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
        <filters>
            <filter>
                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </filter>
        </filters>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>shade</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>dep-to-replace-class-in</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>xyz/morecraft/dev/mcds/processor/ias/mq/MqConnectorBase.class</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer
                            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                        <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                    </transformer>
                    <transformer
                            implementation="org.springframework.boot.maven.PropertiesMergingResourceTransformer">
                        <resource>META-INF/spring.factories</resource>
                    </transformer>
                    <transformer
                            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                        <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                    </transformer>
                    <transformer
                            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                    <transformer
                            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <mainClass>my.class</mainClass>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Just add that class to your project and it will be loaded before the one from the jar? No need to replace it.

Comment: It simply just not work, because this class is used by enother classes from that dependency and they're still using ole one despite having new in the project.

Comment: Did you place it in the same package as the actual class? Also why do you need a separate implementation of that class? Feels like that should be something that should be provided by the used library/framework itself.

Comment: Yes, it is placed in exactly same place. If it could be provided by lib itself there would be no problem. But it can not.

Comment: But then why use the lib? Feels like that you are using the lib in a way it wasn't designed to work. Could you specify the workaround and library in question, as there must be a better way. Overriding classes from a alibrary is generally not a good idea and will eventually lead to all sorts of weird issues. (Yes I now it will as I have on several occasions had to patch WebSphere like that, temporarily :( ).

Comment: The lib is huge and it has a bug in one of its classes.